# Передача данных с минимальной задержкой

Tags: c#, c++, алгоритм, сеть, аудио

Есть потребность в программе, которая позволит джемовать музыкантам по сети, и есть желание ее написать. Для этого требуется, чтобы **доставка** аудио (массивов байтов, размером около 1 кб) осуществлялась с минимальной задержкой (не больше 10 мс). Возможно ли добиться такого? Если да, то как? (Протокол передачи, сжатие, тип сети (p2p или сервер-клиент) и т.д.)  Писать хотелось бы на C# или C++.

**UPD**: интересует еще такой момент. Для уменьшения задержки думаю запаковывать данные в GZip. Скажите, пожалуйста, имеет ли это смысл? Я имею в виду, что не быстрее ли будет просто отсылать незапакованные данные, чем сначала запаковывать, отсылать, а потом распаковывать?

Comment: UDP практически наверняка. И скорее не .NET, а плюсы.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, благодарю за совет.

Comment: А у вас будет такой пинг? Это для начала.

Comment: p2p более вероятно даст меньшую задержку. Хотя может быть конечно ситуация, что маршрутизация до сервера от обоих клиентов в 2 раза меньше прямого маршрута p2p, но думаю это все таки редко. Дальше решаем, что нам важнее если есть задержка передачи порции данных, игнорировать (отбрасывать) и ловить следующую быструю или обязательно дождаться, зато без потерь. Если первое - UDP, второе возможно TCP.

Comment: @VladD, не понял вопроса. Если верить `ping -l 1024 IP`, где IP - это адрес клиента другого провайдера из моего города, то задержка составляет 4-6 мс.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за совет. TCP я отбросил. С ним довольно сложно организовать передачу таких данных, размер которых заведомо не известен.

Comment: А на счет сжатия ... В идеале вам надо что бы одна посылка уместилась в MTU. Заголовок UDP/IP считаем 40 байт. У езернета MTU 1500 байт, в интернете местами может быть уже. Если в MTU укладываетесь - то сжатие, лишние действия.

Comment: Пинг 6 милисекунд, макс. задержка 10. Это значит, что приём и обработка должна проходить за время порядка 4 миллисекунд. Жёсткие требования получаются.

Comment: Не понял, почему с TCP будет сложнее организовать передачу таких данных, размер которых заведомо не известен. Разницы с UDP в этом плане никакой. UDP для Вас предпочтительнее из-за скорости. При его использовании не контролируется вообще ничего: ни порядок доставки, ни целостность. В Вашем случае, при передаче на близкое расстояние и короткими порциями - это играет наруку. Если же нужны будут и целостность данных и правильный порядок их доставки - придется Вам тогда писать свой TCP (раз стандартный отбросили).

Comment: Использование других протоколов над стандартными, наверняка, сразу же даст потерю производительности. Если же Вы собираетесь передавать данные по сути непрерывно (а иначе зачем такая скорость доставки) и при использовании UDP закрывать/открывать соединение при каждой отправке данных, тем самым якобы пытаясь избежать определения размера данных, то получите сразу еще бОльшие потери во времени.

Comment: В целом же, честно говоря, передача данных с задержкой не более 10мс будет в действительности проблемой. Это будет возможно, или в локалке или, грубо говоря, человеку из соседнего города.  VladD написал, что обработка должна проходить за 4мс, но на самом деле, за 7мс. Так как пинг, как я понимаю, считается в обе стороны, а Вам важно только забросить. Но это ничего не меняет по сути. Основное время займет именно поиск/выборка данных откуда-то, их чтение, какая-то минимальная обработка. Хотя если 10мс Вы считаете исключительно на передачу данных по сети, то все зависит от расстояния до клиента.

Comment: @MaxZS, как раз-таки и рассчитываю исключительно на свой город. Обработки как таковой нет: получил - воспроизвел. Все.

Comment: Но ведь поиск контента в БД тоже займет время. Чтение этого контента из БД или файла тоже займет время. Вот так и будет миллисекунда к миллисекунде...

Comment: Действительно ли требуется минимализация задержки? Быть может, стоит посмотреть в сторону буферизации и гнать инфу потоком? 1кб/10мс - совсем немного же - 100кб/сек. MAN, обычно на порядок-два шустрее. В результате будет, конечно, рассинхронизация - но результат будет одинаковым у всех. Простой пример - телефония. По факту, задержки есть, субъективно человек их не слышит.

Answer (score 4):

Сначала отвечу на вопросы, потом с позволения выскажу свое мнение по поводу затеи.

Добиться задержек в 10 мс можно например при подключении точка-точка или в простой локальной сети. Но в вашем случае это почти не реально. Например, прямо сейчас у меня пинг до шлюза 75-80 мс. Кроме того что пакеты будут теряться, так еще они и доставляться будут с непостоянным временем, то есть будет джитер.

Транспортный протокол однозначно UDP. Хотя есть еще [CSTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCTP), но у него ограниченная поддержка со стороны провайдеров, велика вероятность, что найдется узел который будет резать все что не UDP и не TCP. А в Виндоуз он вообще бедный родственник. По прикладному уровню рекомендую ознакомится с [RTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol).

P2P как в [битторенте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB)), вам не поможет в случае если городская сеть жестко централизованна, что часто бывает в небольших городах. То есть если у провайдера один шлюз на всех и к нему централизованно сходятся все каналы от обывателей. Получится, что между участниками будет по одному каналу и битторент будет скорее проигрывать т.к. у него свои накладные тоже есть. Битторент нуждается в избыточных каналах тогда появляется возможность параллельной передачи, в чем и состоит его суть.

Можно попробовать организовать P2P как в [скайпе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype). Например, если среди трех участников окажется что 2 выгоднее быть посредником между 1 и 3, то можно назначить 2 сервером для 1 и 3. Тогда он должен будет передавать для 1: себя и 3, а для 2: себя и 1. Для большего количества участников понадобится подбирать посредников для каждого канала. То есть это задача на [максимальный поток](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5).

Сжимать однозначно надо пробовать, но только не зипом, а аудио-кодеком. Велика вероятность что сжатие\разжатие можно будет делать аппаратно.

Теперь мнение про затею. Почему вы вообще решили что задержки в 10 мс будет достаточно, музыка это тонкая вещь. Большим оркестром обычно управляет дирижер потому что музыканты просто не слышат друг-друга. Рекомендую вам присмотреться к радио.

Comment: У вас что-то странное про P2P написано. Даже при условии "жесткой централизации" сети, P2P все равно выигрывает у серверного решения - потому что сервер же не обязательно в центре сети находится!

Comment: @PavelMayorov Что значит не обязательно? Весь трафик между узлами через центральный сервер гонится, у них нет альтернативных каналов между собой.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что трафик "гонится через центральный сервер"? Центр сети провайдера - это роутер, а не сервер. Сервер будет находиться в лучшем случае - в серверной рядом (короткий луч от роутера), в худшем случае - дома у автора (на таком же длинном луче, как и все клиенты).

Comment: С точки зрения провайдера, гипотетический сервер Ragnar ничем не отличается от любого другого компьютера.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Видимо я не точно сформулировал, под P2P я имею в виду что-то аля битторент или скайп например.

Comment: А что не так в такой сети со скайпом? Да и битторент, хотя и теряет преимущества, все еще остается не хуже серверных решений.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Тем что они теряют смысл, так как нет избыточности... ладно, со скайпом я погорячился.

Comment: Но при этом остается просто хороший протокол передачи файлов с возобновлением.

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно может не до конца разобрался в вопросе! Но тобы отправить данные которые не помещаются в один пакет UDP(TCP) c минимальными задержками и минимальной нагрузкой на сеть можно воспользоваться технологией отправки пула пакетов (SendQueue), реализованной в WinPcap(LibPcap).  Вот здесь все популярно объяснено и с примерами на C# https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com (раздел https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PcapDotNet.DevelopersPack/src/SendingPacketsUsingSendBuffer/Program.cs).